# how to ad a specific number of widget in a row and then move to next row if the number of widgets exceed the desired limit? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a CSV file containing of 6 row and my program makes a button for each row. But it places all the six buttons on the same row. What I want it to do is move to the next row if it has placed three buttons on the first row. How can I do that?

This is the code.

```
  def widget_creator():
        for i in df['Number of studs']:
            txt = 'stud' + str(i)
            rownum=50
            
            ct.CTkButton(canvas, text= txt, corner_radius=10).grid(row=rownum, column=i, pady=100, padx=20, ipadx = 100, ipady=90)
            
                
            
    widget_creator()
```

Here I want it add 30 to `rownum` so it places the rest of the 3 buttons on the 80th row instead of the 50th row.

Thanks

Comment: What are the values of `df['Number of studs']`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```py
  def widget_creator():
        simple_cpt=0
        for i in df['Number of studs']:
            txt = 'stud' + str(i)
            rownum=50
            
            ct.CTkButton(canvas, text= txt, corner_radius=10).grid(row=rownum+int(simple_cpt/3), column=i, pady=100, padx=20, ipadx = 100, ipady=90)
            simple_cpt+=1
            
                
            
    widget_creator()
```